# Segmentation Fault during the execution of Matrix Chain Multiplication

Tags: algorithm, matrix, segmentation-fault, matrix-multiplication

Segmentation Fault during the execution of Matrix Chain Multiplication.

I was writting the code for Matrix Chain Multiplication. I proceeded in the following way.

My program is getting some segmentation fault. I read the code again but I cannot get the issue.

My Logic.
A is a 2D Matrix where A[i][j] is storing the value of the minimum number of multiplications required to multiply C_j to C_i.
B is a 1D Matrix where B[i] stores the Rows of C_{i+1} and columns of C_i.

Initially I assigned the value 0 to each element of the matrix A. The program is able to print the value of A and It also takes the inputs of B.

But it is unable to calculate the number of minimum operations required to multiply C_1 to C_n.
Can you help me figure out the issue

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int Optimal(int **A, int *B, int n);
int main()
{ 
     int n, **A,*B,i,m,j,k;
     printf("\n Enter the number of natrices to be multiplied :");
     scanf("%d",&n);

     A =(int **)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int *));

     { 
          for(i=0; i<=n; i++)
          {        A[i] = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));         
                   for( j=0; j<=n; j++)
                   { 
                            A[i][j]=0;
                   }
          }     

     }
    printf("\n Array entered :\n");
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     { 
          for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
          {
               printf("%d ", A[i][j]); 

          }
          printf("\n");
     }

 B =(int *)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
{   printf("Input the Columns of Matrix %d and Rows of %d",i,i+1);
    scanf("%d",&m);
    B[i]=m;
}

Optimal(A,B,n);
printf("The Minimum Number of Calculations required is %d ",A[1][n]);


return 0;
}

int Optimal(int **A, int *B, int n)
{  
     int m=50000,j,i,k;
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         {
             A[i+1][i]=B[i+1]*B[i]*B[i-1];
         }
  for(k=2;k<n;k++)
    {    

         for(i=k+1;i<=n;i++)
         {

              for(j=1;j<k;j++)
              if(m<A[i+k][i+k-j]*A[i+k-j-1][i]+B[i+k]*B[i+k-j-1]*B[i])
              {
                   m=A[i+k][i+k-j]*A[i+k-j-1][i]+B[i+k]*B[i+k-j-1]*B[i];
              }
              A[i+k][i]=m;
         }
    }

return 0;
}
```

I expect the actual result to be Minimum Number of Multiplications required to multiply the matrices

Comment: In what line do you get the segmentation fault?

Comment: line 41, Optimal(A,B,n);

Comment: Are you sure that each row of A is large enough to hold everything you're assigning to it?

Comment: means My A is (n+1)*(n+1) matrix. I feel it will be able to

Comment: How much does `A[i] = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int))` allocate?

Comment: Fixed It, but the error persists

Comment: In Optimize you access `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         {
             A[i+1][i]=B[i+1]*B[i]*B[i-1];
         }`, which uses indexes from 1 to n+1. What are the valid indexes that can be used with A and B, given their space is allocated with  `malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int))`?

Comment: Oh, But the Issue is with the logic of Optimal

Comment: In `for(i=k+1;i<=n;i++)
         {

              for(j=1;j<k;j++)
              if(m<A[i+k][i+k-j]`, how large can `i+k` be? Can it ever be larger than  `n` ?

Comment: Notice B is sized `n+1` but in the loop i can get to n and you trying to get `B[i+1]` which is `B[n+1]` but last index of B is n...